# Works cited multiple pages in MLA

Tags: style-manuals, mla

I'm currently writing an essay and cites a source multiple times, but at separate pages. Just for clarity's sake, I cited pages 10-11, 15, and 19. The issue is simple enough for in-text citations, but how should I cite this in my works cited page? Should I simply put pp. 10+ (which is one way I saw on a website) or pp. 10-11, 15, 19?

This is in MLA, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's strange is that I have a copy of the *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.) and I can't locate any specific guidance on how to handle multiple locations. It only mentions how to reference a single page or a single range of pages.

However, Simon Fraser University's [MLA Citation Guide](https://www.lib.sfu.ca/help/cite-write/citation-style-guides/mla) may give an indirect example:

> **Works cited**
>
> At the end of your paper, you will list all your sources on a separate page entitled Works Cited (pp. 20-54; pp. 102-116).

Now, that is actually referencing page numbers of the *MLA Handbook* itself, but if the nomenclature it's using is *in* an acceptable MLA format, then your own **Works Cited** entry would likely look the same:

> pp. 10-11; p. 15; p. 19

I can't imagine that reasonable guidance would say to provide a *separate* entry in Works Cited for each identical source but different location.

---

Also note that the use of the plus sign is reserved for periodicals:

> **2.5.1 PLUS SIGN WITH PAGE NUMBER**
>
> If a work in a periodical (journal, magazine, newspaper) is not printed on consecutive pages, include only the first page number and a plus sign, leaving no intervening space.